# Disable javascript in a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element with a a script for a mouseover to show an image. I can't change the HTML, so is it possible to disable the javascript in the link, but still keep the link for the href intact? I cant use the id of the a element since it isn't unique.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
<a id="a211094" onmouseout="etim();" onmouseover="stim('/imgs/7c24b548-4f4c-418e-ad4f-53c73cf52ace/250/250',event,this.id);" href="/products/Computers/Desktops/Acer/Acer-Aspire-TC-705W-Towermodel-1-x-Core-i3-41?prodid=211094"><img src="" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What _can_ you modify?  Can you put extra JavaScript into the page?

Comment: Yeah I can add javascript and jQuery

Comment: your code went missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to make all ancher tag or you can give class for those anchor tags on which you want to perform this and instead of $( "a" ) write $( ".myClass" )

```
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
$( this ).removeAttr("onmouseout");
$( this ).removeAttr("onmouseover");
});
```

use can use attr("disabled", "disable"); to disable it

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("a211094").onmouseover = null
document.getElementById("a211094").onmouseout = null
```

Comment: I cant use the id of the link - I have a bunch of them with different Id. i tried document.getElementsByClassName and nested the a class with the parent cotnainer but that didnt work.

Comment: HTML DOM `getElementsByTagName()` Method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure how to use this?

Comment: smilar way you use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: The link contains an Example with a loop, it will help you

Comment: smilar way you use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("a211094").removeAttribute("onmouseout");
document.getElementById("a211094").removeAttribute("onmouseover");
```

Comment: now you provided 2 wrong answers in a short time WITHOUT any comment or explanation -.- this it not how you should do it.. -1

Comment: Actually, the answer was correct. As I said, it was a typo. Now run along.

Answer (score 0):

If you can consistently access and control the containing element you could try a slightly left-field approach using an onmouseover event on the container.

There's a function called setCapture() which you can call during a mouse event to "capture" all mouse events of that kind for the element it's called against, until a mouseup event or releaseCapture() is called. So you could do something like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $container = jQuery("#<yourcontainerid>");
    $container.on("mouseover", function(e) {
     if (e.target.setCapture) e.target.setCapture(true);
    });

    $container.on("mouseout", function() {
        document.releaseCapture();
    });

});
```

The (true) argument is important (I think, without testing) as it prevents any descendent events firing, which is what you want here.

The mouseout function will then release the capture when it leaves the area of the container.

Will this work? can't say for sure, I haven't tested it in your exact case, but in theory it should!

UPDATE: you can use ".container" rather than "#yourcontainerid" in the JQuery if you so wish to enable this for everything of class container.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort - it didn't work though. Didn't throw an error but the event still fired.